# select filepath is not converted to file in android studio

Tags: java, android

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        selectedFileUri = data.getData();
        selectedFilePath = FilePath.getRealPath(this,selectedFileUri);
        File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
        if (file.isFile()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"not file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(selectedFilePath != null && !selectedFilePath.equals("")){
            tvFileName.setText(selectedFilePath);
           // uploadFile(selectedFilePath);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Cannot upload file to server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

when i select file from device that get their path and when it convert 
    into file and check it is file or not, it give message this is 
    not a file.

Comment: What's your filePath look like?

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Download/17

Comment: you have `selectedFileUri` - it is `content://storage/emulated/0/Download/17` - just use it by means of `ContentResolver` API calls

Comment: sorry how can i resolve it

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Download/flag.png

Comment: where i will change or how it happened

Comment: no, i want to upload all type of file on server but when call upload function it give error selectfilepath is not a file

Comment: because `Uri` != `File` - basically you cannot get any **real path** from `Uri`, more: https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html

Comment: how i will resolve it

Comment: the answer is here: https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html

Comment: sorry sir i can't understand how to get file, i have all ready add content